# How do I uninstall MariaDB on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, mariadb

I have installed [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) from source and now I need to uninstall it. I used these commands to install it:

```
wget http://mirrors.hustunique.com/mariadb/mariadb-10.0.14/source/mariadb-10.0.14.tar.gz
tar -zxvf mariadb-10.0.14.tar.gz
cd mariadb-10.0.14/
apt-get install cmake
apt-get install g++ openssl libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libboost-dev bison
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql \
  -DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DWITH_SSL=system
make && make install
```

How do I uninstall it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easy way for this is installing the `synaptic` package manager by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

And then open synaptic by:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Then search for the package you have installed, `mariadb`, and **mark** it for complete removal and press **apply**.

Comment: I'm search package mariadb in synaptic but any related package seen?

Comment: -1 Package managers like Synaptic can do nothing about software installed with `make install`.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few other options which might be of use:

> sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server

This will remove just the mariadb-server package itself.

> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mariadb-server

This will remove the mariadb-server package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

If you also want to delete your local/config files for mariadb-server then this will work.

> sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mariadb-server

but be careful with that last one. See the disclaimer at [the installion site](http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/universe/m/mariadb-server/uninstall/index.html?)

Comment: this does not answer the question. There is explicitly mentioned that MariaDB was installed from source, so the `apt-get` won't help you.

Answer (score -1):

first stop mariadb service

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

then

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*" # this will delete all database , make backup of your db's
```

source :: [how to remove mariadb fully](http://answers.w3db.xyz/question/how-can-i-completely-removeuninstall-mariadb/)

Comment: -1 because package manager doesn't handle packages that were installed from the source (as question had specified and similar to other downvoted answers).

Comment: @clearimura i removed mariadb like that 10 times ! try it before down voting   .. it done it on my vps 10 times ... i installed multiple times mariadb from source