# How to install mysql V8 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/14/installing-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) in order to install MySql version 8.x in my Ubuntu 16.04.

Before the second step I should have the prompt asking me which version I wish to configure with mysql 8-0 in the list.
But I am getting only the version 5.7, as we can see in the picture below:
[image]

If I go until the final step it will install the version 5.7.

How to install the version 8.x?

Note: previously I had MariaDb instaled, and then I went trough [this steps in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614578/how-do-i-uninstall-mariadb-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/721415) order to uninstall.

```
sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server
```

### Update

In fact something that is not in the tutorial -  we should accept mysql 5.7. In the next window, we will be asked to change to mysql 8.x
See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7F89QS5G3g).

Answer (score 2):

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb

apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server
```

With images: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/14/installing-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're installing version 8. You can download it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/), or through the terminal by doing:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb.
```

Navigate to where the `.deb` package was downloaded and run the following in your terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

You will get a config prompt... Just select "OK".

Since the repository has been installed, run the following to install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

The latest version of MySQL will be installed on your system. During the installation, you should be prompted to create and confirm a MySQL root password.

[image: img_1]

You can confirm whether you want to use the new password encryption feature... It is "recommended" to.

[image: img_2]

After following these steps, **MySQL should have been installed** in your system!

---

### Additionally:

You can log in by running the command:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

That will take you to a MySQL welcome screen such as:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```